# FQL/Graph API retrieves all post from the wall of a Page except one

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

i have the problem that querying posts from the wall of a page returns all posts except one post. I can't explain why this post isn't retrieved.

I hope someone could help me why FQL/Graph API is failing.

https://www.facebook.com/pages/WILIKE-INWI-Uni-Graz/295421080475868

The conecerning post is that one from "Doris Rath".

This is the query i use (which works fine except for this specific post).

```
    $streamQuery = 'SELECT post_id, message, permalink, likes, actor_id, created_time FROM stream WHERE source_id';
    $streamQuery .= '= 295421080475868 AND message != "" LIMIT 1000 OFFSET 0';
```

There's still no explanation why the request does not work ... :(

Still no solution! Have a new ID of a post which returns false: 286722628036968

Comment: Does it appear if you remove `OFFSET 0`?

Comment: As Doris Rath's post is the latest post on the stream, if you post a new post to the stream, does Doris' post appear and not the one that you just posted?

Comment: No it doesn't appear ... My new post is retrieved and displayed in my Array containing the posts from the page though Doris Raths post isn't in the array (so it isn't retrieved).

Comment: That's very strange.  I wish that I had an answer, but I don't.  I can see that the post is set to public.  It might be interesting to see if you're able to retrieve the individual post on it's own?  I've up voted for you anyway.

Comment: This is the ID of the post. GraphAPI just returns "false" ... 168756276550072

Comment: Now i have a second post which returns false if queried.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this post contains the answer to your question [Facebook Graph API returns 'false' even though post is public](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7021099/facebook-graph-api-returns-false-even-though-post-is-public)

The post is not truly public, as when I logged out, the post from Doris Rath was not visible.

The only way to get through this post, would be through a logged in and authorised user with `manage_pages` permission.

Comment: Tried it via the GraphApi Explorer -> GraphApi only returns "false" event manage_pages is set. I could add you as an administrator to my page if you want? Just like the page ...

Comment: I could see the post from Doris when not logged in to Facebook, so I'm not sure that's it.

Comment: That is the post though not accessible via GraphApi/FQL.

Comment: Tried it wiht a user access_token which has full permission (everything possible) but still getting "false"

Answer (score 0):

It is because the user who had posted the message has turned off the app in his profile
[setting of app](https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications)

[image]

Check the image.