# Graph get Comment on a public post

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm working on a project and so far I got all the information I need from graph api, except for the comments on a post. I search for public posts and get the information in a json object. Unfortunately there are no information about the Comments on that post. 
I tried a lot URLs but none of them has worked. Here is an example:

Public Post Search URL = https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=graph+api&type=post

I take a post with comments (I looked up in Browser): 100000056000227_337737819571415

```
https://graph.facebook.com/100000056000227_337737819571415 -> false 

https://graph.facebook.com/100000056000227_337737819571415/comments -> empty array

https://graph.facebook.com/comments/?ids=100000056000227_337737819571415 -> empty array
```

Why do I get an empty array (false)? It's a public post and I can also see it with my Browser. Plus I get the same, when I use my accesstoken with read_streams permissions etc.

Thanks for any Help

P.S. it looks like this, but can an official confirm that?

http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7021099/facebook-graph-api-returns-false-even-though-post-is-public

Comment: Yup, looks like you found the same bug that you linked to.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook Graph API returns 'false' even though post is public](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7021099/facebook-graph-api-returns-false-even-though-post-is-public)

Comment: So you can't see the comments as well? Have you tried the urls? This is what I want to know and maybe a workaround how to read it, because I really need it for my Project. 
If there is no workaround, then I need at least an official Statement for the guys I'm programming