# The Facebook Graph API returns inconsistent results - What am I missing?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've a very simple scenario. I am using [FaceBook API Explorer](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer). I've got two random user profiles that have public posts on their wall:

1. http://www.facebook.com/Arjun (facebook user.id = 7901103)
2. http://www.facebook.com/bashiru.myakasai (facebook user.id=100001044928063)

I'm trying to use fql to access status/links of these users. When I try

```
fql?q=SELECT link_id FROM link WHERE owner = 7901103
```

I receive about 250 rows of data. But when I try the same with the other user id

```
fql?q=SELECT link_id FROM link WHERE owner= 100001044928063
```

I receive [] (an empty dataset!)

What am I doing wrong here? Why can I not fetch public posts from link/stream table when both the profiles are public and all their posts are public?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this answers my question: [Facebook Graph API returns 'false' even though post is public](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7021099/facebook-graph-api-returns-false-even-though-post-is-public). The first profile is truly public (accessible to internet and facebook users) and the second profile is not truly public ( accessible only to logged in users)